# Appmaker Reloading datasource on onInputChange event issue

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table with a search bar above it. The content of the search bar filters the query for the table. I want the data in the table to be reloaded each time the user inputs a letter.

If I set the onValueEdit event to Reload the Datasource, it reloads the data just right, but if I set the onInputChange event to do the reloading, it reloads the table without filtering the query, displaying all of the records. No matter what I type in, it does not filter at all (altough it does seem to reload the datasource), unless I hit enter, fireing the onValueEdit event, when it does the filtering. Any ideas why can't I filter the query with the onInputChange event?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your code of the onInputChange event handler. Showing us your code is a best practice in a proper formulated question.

Comment: I use the preset action "reload datasource" which reads:
widget.datasource.load();
Both of the events use the same preset action.

Comment: And how is your filtering done? Can you show that too?

Comment: That is because the data binding does not take effect during the onInputChange event, the input has to loose focus (i.e. click outside, hit tab or enter key) in order for the binding to complete. However, there is a way to circumvent this and have the onIputChange event complete this binding. All you have to do is enter the following in the onInputChange: `widget.value = event.target.value; widget.datasource.load();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onInputChange event does not appear to support the value binding of a particular widget. Whether this is a bug or the intended behavior is unknown. There are two options to circumvent this behavior however and they are as follows:

Change your code in the onInputChange event to:

Option 1:

```
widget.value = widget.value;
widget.datasource.load();
```

Option 2:

```
widget.value = event.target.value;
widget.datasource.load();
```